# Binary relations - how to find an inverse binary relation - textbook task

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The task is as follows:
Let R be a binary relation on the set X={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. R =
{
(
x,y
)
|
x,y
∈
X,
3  divides
x
−
2y
}.
Find the inverse relation S. Is there a different way to define the set S than just writing S={(2, 1), (5, 1), (8, 1), ...}
If someone could give me a hint in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write: $$S=\{(x,y)\in X^2\mid 3\text{ divides } y-2x\}$$where the roles of $x$ and $y$ are switched.